# How to convert method created to return a promise with $q library to use an ES6 Promise. Angularjs app to Angular4+

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, es6-promise

Since the ES6 Promise does not have a deferred object confused on how to go about converting this to work with ES6 Promises. One solution that I was looking at is to add a deffered object manually to the Promise Constructor.  [see the No deffered section for the example code](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/03/03/second-look-at-promises-native-es6.html)

Reason: **I am converting the angularjs app to angular4** and using it to better understand how to work with ES6 Promises. I was going to add the deferred object, but thought that was too much of a workaround.

```
 function generateImages() {
        console.log('generateImagesCalled')

        // set up promises
        var fullDeferred = $q.defer();
        var thumbDeferred = $q.defer();

        var resolveFullBlob = blob => fullDeferred.resolve(blob);
        var resolveThumbBlob = blob => thumbDeferred.resolve(blob);

        var displayPicture = (url) => {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = url;

            // Generate thumb
            var maxThumbDimension = THUMB_IMAGE_SPECS.maxDimension;
            var thumbCanvas = _getScaledCanvas(image, maxThumbDimension);
            thumbCanvas.toBlob(resolveThumbBlob, 'image/jpeg', THUMB_IMAGE_SPECS.quality);

            // Generate full
            var maxFullDimension = FULL_IMAGE_SPECS.maxDimension;
            var fullCanvas = _getScaledCanvas(image, maxFullDimension);
            fullCanvas.toBlob(resolveFullBlob, 'image/jpeg', FULL_IMAGE_SPECS.quality);
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            displayPicture(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(vm.currentFile);


        return $q.all([fullDeferred.promise, thumbDeferred.promise]).then(results => {
            console.log(results);
            return {
                full: results[0],
                thumb: results[1]
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to convert it to ES6 promise? It will have additional issues with integrating it with Angular digest, something that $q does for you.

Comment: I am converting the app to angular4 and using it to better understand how to work with ES6 Promises. I was going to add the deferred object, but thought that was too much of a workaround

Comment: Makes sense I'd suggest to state this in the question, this will make it more useful to the readers who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some special cases `resolve` and `reject` can be exposed in order to replicate deferreds:

```
let pResolve;
let pReject;
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  pResolve = resolve;
  pReject = reject;
});
```

Or deferred object can be formed:

```
const deferred = {};
deferred.promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Object.assign(deferred, { resolve, reject });
});
```

Since deferreds aren't `Promise` built-in feature and are prone to be antipattern, it's preferable to solve this with constructor function only, when it is applicable.

In the code above `displayPicture` and the fact that promises cannot be formed instantly but on `load` event limits the ways the situation can be efficiently handled. It can be improved with sticking to promises for events (also beneficial for further conversion to `async..await`):

```
    const readerPromise = new Promise(resolve => reader.onload = resolve);
    reader.readAsDataURL(vm.currentFile);

    const blobPromises = readerPromise.then(e => {
      const url = e.target.result;

      const fullBlobPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
        ...
        fullCanvas.toBlob(resolve, ...);
      });

      const thumbBlobPromise = ...;

      return Promise.all([fullBlobPromise, thumbBlobPromise]);
    });
```

The promises should also make use of Angular digests in order to provide same control flow. Since promise internals don't rely on Angular services, there can be a single digest at the end:

```
    return blobPromises.then(
      () => $rootScope.$apply(),
      err => {
        $rootScope.$apply();
        throw err;
      }
    );
    // or
    return $q.resolve(blobPromises);
```

Comment: Why do you even mention deferreds when they shouldn't be used?

Comment: @Bergi For completeness sake, so a reader could estimate options and make own decision on that. the fact that deferreds shouldn't be used most time doesn't mean they shouldn't be used at all. I've had a fair amount of good use cases for them.

Comment: @estus Thanks - got it working - even with your help - it was still mindbending. Been using the deferred pattern for so long. It felt like I was learning promises all over. One question: why do you mention the digest cycle for angular4.  dont think there is a digest cycle in angular4.

Comment: Yes, there are no digests (technically, zones are similar and result in automatic change detection). It wasn't clear from the question if you're gradually refactoring A1 application to convert it to A4 later or rewriting it in A4. The example above is future-proof A1 code, it can be used in A4 as is, but without $rootScope or $q.

Answer (score 1):

in ES6 it would be

```
let resolve1 = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => { 
   if (error) {
      reject();
   } else {
      resolve();
   }
});
```

Do the same for the number of promise you want to resolve, then if you want to run multiple promises, use :

```
Promise.all([resolve1, resolve2]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); 
});
```

Or you can also declare your promises array and then resolve it

```
let resolvedPromisesArray = [Promise.resolve(val1), Promise.resolve(val2)];
let p = Promise.all(resolvedPromisesArray);
```

It will fail if one of the promises is rejected, and will run then if all success ;)

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/