# Angular: Return Observable / ES6 Promise from FileReader

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, es6-promise

I was trying to return result from `FileReader` and I found [this](https://gist.github.com/jollytoad/4201905) implementation. But since it is outdated, I'm wondering how to implement the same using ES6 `Promises` or Rx `Observables`.

Below is my code with reference to the aforementioned link and it works as expected.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import * as XLS from 'xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelReaderService {

  constructor() { }

  importFromExcel(ev): JQueryPromise<any> {
    let deferred = $.Deferred();

    let regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xlsx|.xls)$/;

    let workbook;
    let excelInJSON;

    if (regex.test(ev.target.files[0].name.toString().toLowerCase())) {
      let xlsxflag = false; /*Flag for checking whether excel is .xls format or .xlsx format*/
      if (ev.target.files[0].name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(".xlsx") > 0) {
        xlsxflag = true;
      }

      let fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = (ev) => {
        let binary = "";
        let bytes = new Uint8Array((<any>ev.target).result);
        let length = bytes.byteLength;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }

        /*Converts the excel data in to json*/
        if (xlsxflag) {
          workbook = XLSX.read(binary, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true, cellStyles: true });
          // only first sheet
          excelInJSON = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
          deferred.resolve(excelInJSON);
        }
        else {
          workbook = XLS.read(binary, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true, cellStyles: true });
          excelInJSON = <{}[]>XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
          deferred.resolve(excelInJSON);
        }
      }

      // init read
      if (xlsxflag)
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer((<any>ev.target).files[0]);
      else
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString((<any>ev.target).files[0]);
    } else {
      deferred.reject('Invalid file!');
    }
    return deferred.promise();
  }

}
```

In the consumer `component`

```
this.excelReaderService.importFromExcel(ev).then((result) => {
    this.detailHeadings = Object.keys(result[0]);
    this.detailData = result;
})
```

It'll be great if someone helps me with this as I'm new to asynchronous programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510235/how-to-convert-method-created-to-return-a-promise-with-q-library-to-use-an-es6/46510601#46510601

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is how I did it, in case anyone wants an Angular service that reads Excel files and responds with an `observable` of the content as `JSON`.

I'm using [SheetJS](http://sheetjs.com/) for reading the file and outputting `JSON`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelReaderService {

  constructor() { }

  importFromExcel(ev): Observable<any> {
    let workbook;
    let excelInJSON;

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    // init read
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer((<any>ev.target).files[0]);

    return Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<any[]>): void => {
      // if success
      fileReader.onload = ((ev: ProgressEvent): void => {
        let binary = "";
        let bytes = new Uint8Array((<any>ev.target).result);
        let length = bytes.byteLength;
        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
        }

        // Converts the excel data in to json
        workbook = XLSX.read(binary, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true, cellStyles: true });
        // only first sheet
        excelInJSON = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);

        observer.next(excelInJSON);
        observer.complete();
      } 

      // if failed
      fileReader.onerror = (error: FileReaderProgressEvent): void => {
        observer.error(error);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

From the `component`, just pass the event to this service as shown below and it will respond with the JSON.

```
this.excelReaderService.importFromExcel(ev)
  .subscribe((response: any[]): void => {
    // do something with the response
  });
```

Answer (score 12):

As it's shown in [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510235/how-to-convert-method-created-to-return-a-promise-with-q-library-to-use-an-es6/46510601#46510601), in order to avoid deferred (anti)pattern `FileReader` `load` event should be promisified first:

```
  let fileReader = new FileReader();
  const fileReaderPromise = new Promise(resolve => fileReader.onload = resolve);

  if (xlsxflag)
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer((<any>ev.target).files[0]);
  else
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString((<any>ev.target).files[0]);

  return fileReaderPromise.then(e => {
    let excelInJSON;
    ...
    return excelInJSON;
  });
```

It can also be converted to an observable with [`fromEvent`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromEvent):

```
 const fileReader$ = Observable.fromEvent(fileReader, 'load')
 .map(e => ...)
 .first();

 if (xlsxflag)
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer((<any>ev.target).files[0]);
  else
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString((<any>ev.target).files[0]);
    ...

  return fileReader$;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your solution. Isn't there something as simple as the snippet in my question? Just returning a `promise` or an `observable` that I can subscribe to / consume in a component where I've injected the above `ExcelReaderService`?

Comment: The snippet is supposed to reside in `importFromExcel` method you've posted. You create `fileReaderPromise` and return it from there.

Answer (score 4):

Improving upon @karthikaruna's answer above, I'd add with Observables, it's easy to make a `.pipe` chain return what you want from a `File` object:

(please note that these types might not be 100% correct).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelReaderService {

    public importFromExcel(ev): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.fileToString(ev.target.files[0])
            .pipe(
                // convert from file contents to Excel rows
                map((binary: string): any[] => {
                    // Converts the excel data in to json
                    const workbook = XLSX.read(binary, { type: 'binary', cellDates: true, cellStyles: true });
                    // only first sheet
                    const excelInJSON = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);
                    return excelInJSON;
                }),
            );
    } // end importFromExcel()

    private fileToString(file: File): Observable<string> {
        return Observable.create(
            (sub: Subscriber<string>): void => {
                const r = new FileReader;
                // if success
                r.onload = (ev: ProgressEvent): void => {
                    sub.next((ev.target as any).result);
                };
                // if failed
                r.onerror = (ev: FileReaderProgressEvent): void => {
                    sub.error(ev);
                };
                r.readAsText(file);
            }
        );
    } // end fileToString()

}
```