# Async event and exception

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-2017

in ES7 we will be having `async` and `await` keyword for JS. It looks very promising for regular functions. But how do we handle exception in async events?

for example

```
async badFunc()
{
    throw "bad";
}

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = async function ()
{
    await badFunc();
}
```

Based on my understanding the `async` function will be a syntax sugar which will be using `Promise`'s `resolve` and `reject` function under the hood. So the exception will only be caught if the caller is using `await` keyword.

In the above example `await badFunc();` line will catch the exception and rethrow it. But since the `onload` handler is probably not calling `await` on the callback and thus the exception will get lost in the void. even `window.onerror` can't catch it.

So my question is. What should the right way to use await inside event so that the exception will not get lost?

Comment: wrap the await in a  `try ... catch` block

Comment: @0.sh and how do we rethrow it so that the global handler can have a chance to do something?

Comment: Event handlers have no notion of promises, so assigning an async function to an event handler seems mostly pointless unless you handle the logic within it. and even then, you're losing the ability to return false.

Comment: @Steve, are you talking about throwing the exception caused by `await badFunc()` ?

Comment: It is ES2017, not ES7. While existing post answers the question directly, it's beneficial for control flow to [promisify FileReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513123/angular-return-observable-es6-promise-from-filereader) instead of handling promises inside its callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, async-await is just a syntax sugar for promises. Any **async** function returns a `Promise` that is *resolved* when the function returns, or is *rejected* when the function throws an exception.

```
async foo() {
  return 1;
}

const promise1 = foo(); // here we have a promise that will   resolve in 1

async bar() {
  throw new Error('something went wrong');
}

const promise2 = bar(); // here we have a promise that will be rejected with an error.
```

These promises can be handled as any regular promises, like:

```
foo().then(…).catch(…);
```

Inside of an *async* function you may use the **await** keyword. If it is followed by a promise (or a promise-like object), it will pause the execution of an async function and wait for the promise to resolve. If the promise resolves its result will be used as the result of an expression. If it is rejected, an exception will be thrown on the line where *await* is used.

Example:

```
const promise3 = async baz() {
  const boo = await foo(); //  (1)
  const zoo = await bar(); // (2)
}
```

(1) Pauses on this line and waits for the promise to resolve; After the promise resolves, boo becomes equal 1.

(2) Pauses on this line and waits for the promise to resolve; After the promise rejects, throws an exception.

Errors thrown by *await* can be captured using try…catch. If they are not, they will bubble up, which means that `promise3` will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

```
async badFunc()
{
    throw "bad";
}

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function ()
{
    (async()=>{
        await badFunc();
    })().then(()=>()).catch(e=>console.log(e))
}
```

I've replaced the async event handler with a normal event handler that invokes an internal async IIFE. The `console.log(e)` can be replaced with whatever error routine you find helpful.

Note that you can return a standard value from the handler by placing a '`return x`' at the end -- this will always fire, before badFunc's Promise is evaluated, even if it's rejected. You cannot return a value based upon the *resolved* status of the internal promise, unless your callback expects and will evaluate a Promise return value. You could chain to another event listener.

Also, while `window.onerror` won't catch the error, `unhandledrejection` will catch it in Chrome and SOME other browsers. Firefox notably will not. This can be good enough for debugging code, but not to catch anything in production out in the wild.