# How can I use a callback function in typescript while using FileReader? Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, callback

I'm facing some difficults trying to apply promises/callbacks to my TypeScript function.

I need to gather reader.onloadend's result and send it to my nodejs express backend (using services), but the only way that I was able to do it was through setTimeout, and I'm pretty sure that if I can do it by using setTimeout, I can also do it by using promises/callbacks...

I just don't know how, I tried to pass callback as parameter and call it later, but I'm getting "callback is not a function".

```
var reader = new FileReader();
let inf = {}
let base64data;
let splitUrl = this.url.split('-')[4];    


reader.onloadend = function() {
  base64data = reader.result;

  inf = { base64: base64data, id: splitUrl }
}

setTimeout(() => {

  console.log(inf);
}, 3000);
```

Hey guys, I fixed it by changing from "function (){}" to an arrow function!

Comment: Have you considered adding Observable support to your reads like in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513123/angular-return-observable-es6-promise-from-filereader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function is called when the load has ended. Using `setTimeout` is a bad idea because it is completely decoupled with the load's asynchronous timing.

Just do what you want to do with the result in the callback.

```
reader.onloadend = () => {
  base64data = reader.result;

  inf = { base64: base64data, id: splitUrl }
  console.log(inf);
  doStuffWithFile(inf);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. The problem is that when I try to do stuff inside the callback, I get the error message saying that "myService does not exist on type 'FileReader'   EDIT: I just realize that after changing the normal function to an arrow function I was able to call my service! I'm sorry about that, and thanks!

Comment: Yep, you should always be using arrow functions in Angular. Arrow functions enclose a lexical `this` that always refers to the context it was called in (the component).