# How do I test an observable inside mergeMap when outer observable uses FileReader

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine, rxjs-observables

I'm trying to test a file upload. I wrapped the `FileReader()` into an observable according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513123/angular-return-observable-es6-promise-from-filereader):

```js
onFileSelected(event: any) {
    this.importJsonFileToString(event.target.files[0])
        .pipe(
            map(jsonString => JSON.parse(jsonString)),
            mergeMap(uploadData => this.httpService.postToB(uploadData)),
            tap(() => console.log('after mergeMap'))
        )
        .subscribe();
}

private importJsonFileToString(file: any): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber<any>): void => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        fileReader.onload = (): void => {
            subscriber.next((<any>fileReader).result.toString());
            subscriber.complete();
        };
        fileReader.onerror = (error: any): void => {
            subscriber.error(error);
        };
    });
}
```

The problem appears while testing the code. I use the following spec with `HttpClientTestingModule` to catch the Request of the inner Subscription:

```js
it('should subscribe to inner observable with custom observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    const file = new File(['{"nameA":"nameA"}'], 'testFile', { type: 'text/plain' });
    const dummyEvent = { target: { files: [file] } };

    const parseSpy = spyOn(JSON, 'parse').and.callThrough();

    app.onFileSelected(dummyEvent);

    const postRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(req => req.method === 'POST');
    postRequest.flush('');
}));
```

The Request does not get recorded. I also tried adding some ticks because I assume there is a problem with the asynchronous nature of the `FileReader`.

I also tried outer and inner request instead, which resolves without any problem:

```js
nestedHttpCall() {
    return this.httpService
        .getFromA()
        .pipe(mergeMap(response => this.httpService.postToB(response)))
        .subscribe();
}
```

Spec:

```js
it('should subscribe to inner observable', () => {
    app.nestedHttpCall();

    const getRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(req => req.method === 'GET');
    getRequest.flush({ nameA: 'nameA' });

    const postRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(req => req.method === 'POST');
    postRequest.flush('');

    expect(getRequest.request.method).toBe('GET');
    expect(postRequest.request.method).toBe('POST');
});
```

Is my approach even correct to test the file upload?

Comment: Does the `console.log('after mergeMap')` fire?

Comment: No, it does not...

Answer (score 0):

I'm *guessing* that you are finishing your `it()` before your asychronous call even starts... which makes no sense to me because you're using `fakeAsync`, but this *might* get you closer to an answer.

Try

```js
asynch onFileSelected(event: any) {
  return this.importJsonFileToString(event.target.files[0]).pipe(
    map(jsonString => JSON.parse(jsonString)),
    mergeMap(uploadData => this.httpService.postToB(uploadData)),
    tap(() => console.log('after mergeMap'))
  ).toPromise();
}
```

And then you can use `await` to ensure it finishes.

```js
it('should subscribe to inner observable with custom observable', fakeAsync(() => {
    const file = new File(['{"nameA":"nameA"}'], 'testFile', { type: 'text/plain' });
    const dummyEvent = { target: { files: [file] } };

    const parseSpy = spyOn(JSON, 'parse').and.callThrough();

    await app.onFileSelected(dummyEvent);

    const postRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(req => req.method === 'POST');
    postRequest.flush('');
}));
```

**Oh wait!!** You're not using [`tick()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick&ved=2ahUKEwj59_7gwY36AhXEMDQIHVhjB9gQFnoECBAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw378tMmRCFbFzv3O0RQeqf6)! That's most likely the issue.

Comment: As I wrote, I already tried adding some ticks. I will try the promise path tomorrow.

Comment: Making it onFileSelected return a promise I have to make the it() async. The result is: `Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL) at <Jasmine>` :(

Comment: While testing, is your httpService configured to return a mock value?

Comment: U mean via httpTestingController, then yes. I can debug to the point where I am running into merge map. Test looks like the one you posted, except using async instead of fakeasync.

Comment: Test just `this.httpService.postToB(uploadData)` and ensure that's writing and returning as expected?